# EXCEL VBA Split Function - Specifying ALL Symbols and Letters as Delimiters

Tags: excel, vba, string, text-extraction

I am working in EXCEL VBA and I have a large number of strings like this:

```
str = "aei jt098_374!6.90*9U35t9miK34=90^1-349j582ge&%$g2=045 un=n20#^9i1=n5g76]90 82n3]-568@2^68*)85f1=0947f]287j"
```

I need to extract all numbers from these strings while recognizing ALL non-numeric characters (all letters and all symbols as delimiters (except for the period (.)). For example, the value of the first several numbers extracted from the example string above should be:

```
098
374
6.90
9
35
9
```

I can imagine doing this with the Split function in VBA, however: how does one specify ALL upper and lowercase letters and ALL symbols except for the period (.) as the delimiters (including blank spaces)?

Is there a way to specify EVERYTHING except 0 thru 9 and . as the delimiters for the Split function?

In other words, one can certainly specify the delimiters by positively identifying them in the list of delimiters, but is there a way to negatively identify the delimiters by essentially saying - let the delimiters be EVERYTHING except these listed characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be doable with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops).

```
' Under Tools > References
' add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Sub ExtractTheNumbers()
    Dim s As String
    s = "aei jt098_374!6.90*9U35t9miK34=90^1-349j582ge&%$g2=045 un=n20#^9i1=n5g76]90 82n3]-568@2^68*)85f1=0947f]287j"

    Dim regEx As RegExp
    Set regEx = New RegExp
    
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "\d+\.?\d*"
    End With

    Dim matches As MatchCollection
    Set matches = regEx.Execute(s)
            
    Dim m As Match
    For Each m In matches
        Debug.Print m.Value
    Next
End Sub
```

returns

```
098
374
6.90
9
35
9
34
90
1
349
582
2
045
20
9
1
5
76
90
82
3
568
2
68
85
1
0947
287
```

Comment: The question of how to represent all non-digits (except decimal separators) as delimiters in a split routine challenged me, so I posted a late alternative answer to your working regex solution which might interest you, too +:)

Answer (score 0):

> The question of how to represent **all non-digits** *(except decimal separators)* as delimiters
> in a split routine challenged me. *- Note that I don't pretend having found the best or quickiest solution, but for sure an innovative one.*

In order to find a single **delimiter** for **all non-digits** *(or at least a mini group of delimiters)*, the following tricky steps revealed to be necessary:

-a) **atomize** a string argument `s` into single symbols (see function `str2arr()`)

-b) get 1-based **positions** within a *pattern array* via `Match` function, where omitting the 3rd argument (!) allows to group all non-digits to a very small number of position types; note that this assembles not only A-Z, but also all *diacritic* or *accented letters* to the last pattern position represented by letter **`A`**

-c) **rework matches** based on these positions (minus 5) *making digits readable* (5 is position of first digit in the pattern) and  *excluding all non-digits* via space as new default delimiter

-d) execute `Application.Trim` (reducing several *spaces* to single ones) on the joined result string and **split** again via a universal **space** delimiter (now representing **all symbols** to be excluded!)

```
Function NumsOnly(s As String)
    Const NumSep = ".", Space = " "
    Dim pattern: pattern = str2arr("'.+-0123456789A")   ' define pattern array
'a) get symbols array from string argument s
    Dim symbols: symbols = str2arr(s)                   ' atomize string input, too
'b) get 1-based positions within pattern array (omitting 3rd argument!)
    Dim x:       x = Application.Match(symbols, pattern)
'c) rework matches
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(symbols)
        x(i + 1) = x(i + 1) - 5                         ' make digits readable (based on position)
        If symbols(i) = NumSep Then x(i + 1) = NumSep   ' include numeric separator
        Select Case x(i + 1)
            Case Is < 0, 10                             ' exclude any other symbols (via space)
                x(i + 1) = Space
        End Select
    Next i
'd) return only digits
'   (join to string, reduce several spaces to single ones and split via default space delimiter)
    NumsOnly = Split(Application.Trim(Join(x, "")))
End Function
```

**Help function `str2arr()`**

```
Function str2arr(ByVal s As String)
    s = StrConv(s, vbUnicode)
    str2arr = Split(Left(s, Len(s) - 1), vbNullChar)
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
Sub testNumsOnly()
    Dim s As String: s = "abA1290x yz156.0x@/\,+-'"
    Dim results:     results = NumsOnly(s)
    Debug.Print "Numeric tokens: " & Join(results, "|")
End Sub
```

**Result in VB Editor's immediate window:**

```
Numeric tokens: 1290|156.0
```